# what is the difference between sgbm and sgm

Tags: opencv3.0

I am newbie to Opencv.  I am trying ***stereosgbm compute*** function in gpu.  I did not find any cuda porting as of now from opencv.

I want to know the difference between semi-global matching and semi-global block matching.  But i did not find any difference.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> StereoSGBM is OpenCV's implementation of Hirschmüller's original SGM algorithm. The implementation is a bit different from the original algorithm design.
>
> - The original algorithm uses pixel-wise aggregation cost, while StereoSGBM allows matching blocks. If the block size is set to 1, it's the same as working on pixels.
> - Mutual information cost function is not implemented in StereoSGBM.
> - OpenCV's SGBM focuses on speed. Therefore, by default, StereoSGBM is single-pass (i.e. it calculates the matching cost in fewer directions). You can set mode=StereoSGBM::MODE_HH to calculate the cost in all 8 directions.
> - StereoSGBM also implements sub-pixel estimation proposed by Birchfield
>     et al.

I suggest reading OpenCV's documentation about StereoSGBM via this link https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d85/classcv_1_1StereoSGBM.html  This document describes the main differences between OpenCV's implementation (SGBM) and original SGM.

If you are interested, E. Dall’Asta, R. Roncella's paper, A COMPARISON OF SEMI-GLOBAL AND LOCAL DENSE MATCHING ALGORITHMS FOR SURFACE RECONSTRUCTION, discussed the differences between OpenCV's SGBM implementation and Hirschmüller's SGM.

Hope this answer helps you.